# Distribution of a sum

Tags: probability, matrices, optimization, chi-squared

let us assume $f<k$ and 
let us assume we have a vector z , which contains $\frac{k^2 -k}{2}$ entries --- z follows a multivariate normal distribution and a vector d which contains $kf - \frac{f(f-1)}{2}$ entries but we dont know them. A is a Matrix such that $Ad$ makes sense.

We are looking at

$$(z-Ad)^{T}(z-Ad) \to min$$

where the solution (if A is regular) must be : $$d=(AA^{T})^{-1}A^{T}z$$

but the minimization problem $$S=(z-Ad)^{T}(z-Ad) \to min$$ should follow a generalized chi square distribution -- we can write 
$$S= z^{T}z +(Ad)^{T}Ad $$

so there are $z^2$ .. therefore we have the squares of normally distributed entries -- but what about the other term ? ... d can be expressed in terms of A and z -- is this enough?

my lecturer also told me , it should be possible to write S as a sum of $$\frac{(k-f)^2 -(k+f)}{2}$$ summands with application of the singular value decomposition to A ... but i dont see it ... hope you can help :)

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly he/she was talking about the case where $A$ has full column rank, otherwise what he/she said is false. In the extreme case where $A=0$, the minimum $S$ is always $\sum_{j=1}^{(k^2-k)/2}z_j^2$, which is the sum of $(k^2-k)/2$ independent summands, not fewer.

In general (regardless of whether $AA^T$ is invertible or not), a global minimiser of $\|z-Ad\|^2$ is given by $d=A^+z$, where $A^+$ denotes the [Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $A$. If $A=U\Sigma V^T$ is a singular value decomposition, then $A^+=V\Sigma^+U^T$, where $\Sigma^+$ is obtained by replacing all nonzero entries (if any) in the main diagonal of $\Sigma^T$ by their reciprocals. The minimum value of $\|z-Ad\|^2$ is thus
$$
S=\|(I-AA^+)z\|^2=\|(I-\Sigma\Sigma^+)(U^Tz)\|^2
=\left\|\pmatrix{0\\ &I_{n-r}}(U^Tz)\right\|^2,
$$
where $n=\frac{k^2-k}2$ and $r=\operatorname{rank} A$. If we put $v=U^Tz$, then $S=\sum_{j=r+1}^n v_j^2$ is a sum of $n-r$ square terms.

Now, if $A$ has full column rank, then $r=kf-\frac{f(f-1)}2$ and hence $n-r=\frac{(k-f)^2-(k+f)}2$.

Comment: This answer is Fantastic!! Thank you Very  much !! Just a small question : what can we say About the variances of $(v_j)^2$ ?

Comment: @Calculator123 If $z \sim N(\mathbf m, C)$, then $v=U^Tz \sum N(U^T\mathbf m, U^TCU)$. So, if $\mu$ is the $j$-th entry of $U^T\mathbf m$ and $\sigma^2$ is the $j$-th diagonal entry of $U^TCU$, then $v_j \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Hence (if I calculate correctly)
\begin{align}
var(v_j^2)
&=E(v_j^4)-E(v_j^2)^2\\
&=(\mu^4+6\mu^2\sigma^2+3\sigma^4)-(\mu^2+\sigma^2)^2\\
&=4\mu^2\sigma^2 + 2\sigma^4.
\end{align}
However, note that $v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n$ in general are not independent (unless $z\sim$ some $N(0,\sigma^2 I)$, so I'm not sure if the variance of $v_j^2$ is all that useful.

Comment: Yes z is normally Distributed Witz mean Zero!  So i guess the summands of S are Independent:) Thank you: )